# cakephp pagination query with hasAndBelongsToMany

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm not too great with sql anyway but I'm having trouble getting a particular query to work.

I have archives and images as tables. They are connected by a archives_images table. I have the $id for the archive I want and I'm trying to paginate the Images which have records in the archives_images table beside the archive_id I have.

The code I'm trying (This is the most correct one - I've been trying for a while now)

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions' => array(
                            'Image.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'),
                            'ArchivesImage.archive_id'=>$id
                            ),
        'limit' => 48
    );
```

But obviously that's giving me an error because there's no 'ArchivesImage.archive_id' in 'where clause'

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'joins'=>array(
          array(
             'table'=>'archives_images',
             'Alias'=>'ArchivesImage',
             'type'=> 'INNER',
             'conditions'=>array(
                  'ArchivesImage.archive_id=Archive.id'
                      )
         ),
          array(
             'table'=>'images',
             'Alias'=>'Image',
             'type'=> 'INNER',
             'conditions'=>array(
                  'Image.id=ArchivesImage.image_id'
                      )
         )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
                        'Image.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')
                        ),
    'limit' => 48,
    'recursive'=>-1
);
```